# TextField in PopOver with strange behavior

Tags: javafx, textfield, popover, controlsfx

I have a PopOver with a TextField with a strange behavior, this PopOver it's owned by other TextField because when I type the word '`Fernández'` all keys are processed by the internal TextField except when I type a stressed vowel like '`á`' that it's collected by the external TextField.

[PopOver owned by TextField](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKnAu.png)

But when i show the same PopOver owned by a button works fine and the internal TextField receives the letter 'á'

[PopOver owned by Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbkCY.png)

I would appreciate any help to solve it.

EDIT: Here you can see an example code to show this.

public class PopOverTest extends Application {

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    CustomTextField externo = new CustomTextField();
    ImageView imgView = new ImageView(new Image("test/image.png"));
    externo.setLeft(imgView);

    CustomTextField interno = new CustomTextField();

    PopOver popOver = new PopOver();
    popOver.setContentNode(interno);
    popOver.stArrowLocation(PopOver.ArrowLocation.TOP_LEFT);

    imgView.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
        popOver.show(imgView);

    });


    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(externo);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this.

Changing the external Textfield EventDispatcher and the problem is resolved

```
EventDispatcher dispatcher = externalTextField.getEventDispatcher();
```

then on focus of the internal TextField

```
externalTextField.setEventDispatcher(interntalTextField.getEventDispatcher());
```

and when lost focus restore the EventDispatcher

```
externalTextField.setEventDispatcher(dispatcher);
```

That's all folks!